# Show that $\det(A+B)=\det(C)$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $A,B,C$ be $n \times n $ matrix such that for each $i \in \{2,...,n\}$ we have following row $i$ of $A$ = row $i$ of $B$ = row $i$ of $C$. Moreover, we have other extra condition such that row $1$ of $A$ + row $1$ of $B$ = row $1$ of $C$

Show that $\det(A+B)=\det(C)$

My attempts are the following and I am sorry for the matrices because I am new to write matrices in latex.
I have these matrices s.t $A=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1} & a_{2}\ldots  & a_{n} \\
d_{21} & d_{22} &  \\
: &  &  \\
d_{n1} & \ldots  & d_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}$
, $B=\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1} & b_{2}\ldots  & b_{n} \\
d_{21} & d_{22} &  \\
: &  &  \\
d_{n1} & \ldots  & d_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}$ and  $C=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1}+b_{1} & a_{2}+b_{2}\ldots  & a_{n}+b_{n} \\
2d_{21} & 2d_{22} &  \\
: &  &  \\
2d_{n1} & \ldots  & 2d_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}$

$\det(C)= 2^{n-1}.\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1}+b_{1} & a_{2}+b_{2}\ldots  & a_{n}+b_{n} \\
d_{21} & d_{22} &  \\
: &  &  \\
d_{n1} & \ldots  & d_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}$

Any suggestions?

Comment: The equality $\det C = 2^{n-1} \cdot$ some matrix can't be true. You mean the determinant of that matrix.

Comment: The determinant map is multilinear on rows (and on columns) of square matrices, and what you are describing is additivity in the first row. This can be proven without difficulty (but a lot of symbols) by expanding the determinants by cofactors along the first row.

Comment: Yes, result will be match if I use cofactor expansion along the first row for all matrices. But is there anyway that we can calculate it?

Comment: @AlvinL Why? Every row except first row is multiplied by 2 and I can take 2 parentheses.

Comment: Looking at your question once more, I think there's an error. I think it should be $\det C = \det A + \det B$. Can you confirm that it should be $\det C = \det(A + B)$ instead?

Comment: Probably you are right, @TheoBendit